# Dataclasses and property decorator

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

I've been reading up on Python 3.7's dataclass as an alternative to namedtuples (what I typically use when having to group data in a structure). I was wondering if dataclass is compatible with the property decorator to define getter and setter functions for the data elements of the dataclass. If so, is this described somewhere? Or are there examples available?

Comment: https://florimond.dev/blog/articles/2018/10/reconciling-dataclasses-and-properties-in-python/

Comment: this just points out the issue, but does not resolve it. for example properties with no default value passed in to `__init__` is an unhandled case.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

It sure does work:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Test:
    _name: str="schbell"

    @property
    def name(self) -> str:
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, v: str) -> None:
        self._name = v

t = Test()
print(t.name) # schbell
t.name = "flirp"
print(t.name) # flirp
print(t) # Test(_name='flirp')
```

In fact, why should it not? In the end, what you get is just a good old class, derived from type:

```
print(type(t)) # <class '__main__.Test'>
print(type(Test)) # <class 'type'>
```

Maybe that's why properties are nowhere mentioned specifically. However, the [PEP-557's Abstract](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/#id32) mentions the general usability of well-known Python class features:

> Because Data Classes use normal class definition syntax, you are free
>   to use inheritance, metaclasses, docstrings, user-defined methods,
>   class factories, and other Python class features.

Comment: I guess I kinda wish that dataclasses would allow for a property to override the getting or setting without having to name fields with a leading underscore.  Part of the data class sugar is the initialization which would mean that you'd end up with `Test(_name='foo')` -- that means that you're interface would differ from your creation. This is a small price but still, there is so little difference between dataclasses and named tuples that this would be something else useful (that differentiates it more and hence, gives it more purpose).

Comment: @Marc They do! Use classic getters and setters and call the setter function in the init instead of assigning directly. `def set_booking_ref(self, value:str): self._booking_ref = value.strip()` ... `booking_ref = property(get_booking_ref, set_booking_ref)` ... `def __init__(self, booking_ref :str): self.set_booking_ref(self, booking_ref)`. Not sure how you would do this with `@property` decorator.

Comment: @Marc I had the same concern. [here](https://blog.florimondmanca.com/reconciling-dataclasses-and-properties-in-python) is a good explanation of how to solve this problem.

Comment: @JorenV thank you for the explanation.  That is the best way IMHO to do it currently.  I *still* wish dataclasses even did that dance for you (but I can settle for this) - it is more explicit after all.

Comment: @JorenV, Thank you for the link to that explanation. I read through it and tried implementing it myself and then started to wonder why I was going through all this trouble when I could just keep a regular class instead of dataclass and avoid all of this.

Comment: @JorenV, you should consider creating an answer with your comment, as it's a great solution but is somewhat buried in the comments here.

Comment: @DanCoates, thanks for pointing it out. I just created a proper answer.

Comment: Providing a private member as a public dataclass field is an anti pattern.

Comment: I just tested it and you should NOT do it if the setter is performing validation on the property, because the object construction will not call it. I went for regular class instead.

Comment: I like your example name ;-)

Answer (score 31):

A solution with minimal additional code and no hidden variables is to override the `__setattr__` method to do any checks on the field:

```
@dataclass
class Test:
    x: int = 1

    def __setattr__(self, prop, val):
        if prop == "x":
            self._check_x(val)
        super().__setattr__(prop, val)

    @staticmethod
    def _check_x(x):
        if x <= 0:
            raise ValueError("x must be greater than or equal to zero")
```

Comment: This is a pretty solid solution. You bypass the need for a property method, which can be either a plus or minus. Personally I like the concept of properties because I feel it's truly Pythonic, but I still went ahead and upvoted as this is definitely a valid approach.

Comment: My use-case was to override some templated `Path` instances based on dataclass field values, so `property` was too much of verbosity: `_`-prefixed variable + property definition + setter with `Path` overrides, for each variable. This solution is consice as hell! Thank you very much!

Comment: With the `property` solution, when using named arguments to the constructor, you need to use `_name=...` (with a leading underscore), which leaks implementation details of `Test`. This `__setattr__` solution doesn't have that issue.

Answer (score 22):

**TWO VERSIONS THAT SUPPORT DEFAULT VALUES**

Most published approaches don't provide a readable way to set a default value for the property, which is quite an important part of *dataclass*. Here are two possible ways to do that.

The **first way** is based on the approach referenced by *@JorenV*. It defines the default value in `_name = field()` and utilises the observation that if no initial value is specified, then the setter is passed the *property* object itself:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class Test:
    name: str
    _name: str = field(init=False, repr=False, default='baz')

    @property
    def name(self) -> str:
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value: str) -> None:
        if type(value) is property:
            # initial value not specified, use default
            value = Test._name
        self._name = value


def main():
    obj = Test(name='foo')
    print(obj)                  # displays: Test(name='foo')

    obj = Test()
    obj.name = 'bar'
    print(obj)                  # displays: Test(name='bar')

    obj = Test()
    print(obj)                  # displays: Test(name='baz')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The **second way** is based on the same approach as *@Conchylicultor*: bypassing the *dataclass* machinery by overwriting the field outside the class definition.

Personally I think this way is cleaner and more readable than the first because it follows the normal *dataclass* idiom to define the default value and requires no 'magic' in the setter.

Even so I'd prefer everything to be self-contained... perhaps some clever person can find a way to incorporate the field update in `dataclass.__post_init__()` or similar?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Test:
    name: str = 'foo'

    @property
    def _name(self):
        return self._my_str_rev[::-1]

    @_name.setter
    def _name(self, value):
        self._my_str_rev = value[::-1]


# --- has to be called at module level ---
Test.name = Test._name


def main():

    obj = Test()
    print(obj)                      # displays: Test(name='foo')

    obj = Test()
    obj.name = 'baz'
    print(obj)                      # displays: Test(name='baz')

    obj = Test(name='bar')
    print(obj)                      # displays: Test(name='bar')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: As someone pointed out on another thread, if you find yourself going to this much trouble then it's probably better to just use a normal class...

Comment: Hyperbole much? Trivial one-liners like `Test.name = Test._name` are hardly "much trouble." Although noxious boilerplate, that's still *much* less boilerplate than you'd inflict on yourself with the equivalent normal class (i.e., non-`@dataclass`).

Comment: If anyone's interested, also @MartinCR, I came up with a metaclass approach which is inspired in part by this post. I've determined it to be very efficient, because it generates a `__post_init__` which only runs an initial time to set up properties so it plays well with dataclasses. You can find it in the [gist here](https://gist.github.com/rnag/d14b05680094b871935a9a30d43d5c0d).

Answer (score 15):

An `@property` is typically used to store a seemingly public argument (e.g. `name`) into a private attribute (e.g. `_name`) through getters and setters, while dataclasses generate the `__init__()` method for you. 
The problem is that this generated `__init__()` method should interface through the public argument `name`, while internally setting the private attribute `_name`.
This is not done automatically by dataclasses.

In order to have the same interface (through `name`) for setting values and creation of the object, the following strategy can be used (Based on [this blogpost](https://florimond.dev/blog/articles/2018/10/reconciling-dataclasses-and-properties-in-python/), which also provides more explanation):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Test:
    name: str
    _name: str = field(init=False, repr=False)

    @property
    def name(self) -> str:
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name: str) -> None:
        self._name = name
```

This can now be used as one would expect from a dataclass with a data member `name`:

```
my_test = Test(name='foo')
my_test.name = 'bar'
my_test.name('foobar')
print(my_test.name)
```

The above implementation does the following things:

- The `name` class member will be used as the public interface, but it actually does not really store anything
- The `_name` class member stores the actual content. The assignment with `field(init=False, repr=False)` makes sure that the `@dataclass` decorator ignores it when constructing the `__init__()` and `__repr__()` methods.
- The getter/setter for `name` actually returns/sets the content of `_name`
- The initializer generated through the `@dataclass` will use the setter that we just defined. It will not initialize `_name` explicitly, because we told it not to do so.

Comment: This is the best answer IMHO but lacks the (important) ability to set default values for properties that aren't specified when the class is instantiated. See my answer for a tweak to allow that.

Comment: Note that mypy will complain about the double definition of `name`! No runtime errors though.

Comment: FWIW, I added an approach with meta classes that helps support properties with default values

Answer (score 7):

Currently, the best way I found was to overwrite the dataclass fields by property in a separate child class.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class _A:
    x: int = 0

class A(_A):
    @property
    def x(self) -> int:
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value: int):
        self._x = value
```

The class behave like a regular dataclass. And will correctly define the `__repr__` and `__init__` field (`A(x=4)` instead of `A(_x=4)`. The drawback is that the properties cannot be read-only.

[This blog post](https://blog.florimond.dev/reconciling-dataclasses-and-properties-in-python), tries to overwrite the wheels dataclass attribute by the `property` of the same name.
However, the `@property` overwrite the default `field`, which leads to unexpected behavior.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class A:

    x: int

    # same as: `x = property(x)  # Overwrite any field() info`
    @property
    def x(self) -> int:
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value: int):
        self._x = value

A()  # `A(x=<property object at 0x7f0cf64e5fb0>)`   Oups

print(A.__dataclass_fields__)  # {'x': Field(name='x',type=<class 'int'>,default=<property object at 0x>,init=True,repr=True}
```

One way solve this, while avoiding inheritance would be to overwrite the field outside the class definition, after the dataclass metaclass has been called.

```
@dataclass
class A:
  x: int

def x_getter(self):
  return self._x

def x_setter(self, value):
  self._x = value

A.x = property(x_getter)
A.x = A.x.setter(x_setter)

print(A(x=1))
print(A())  # missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

It should probably possible to overwrite this automatically by creating some custom metaclass and setting some `field(metadata={'setter': _x_setter, 'getter': _x_getter})`.

Comment: For your first approach, it seems also possible to make it inside-out. Defining `_A` with getter and setter while `@dataclass` the outer `A(_A)`.

Answer (score 5):

Some wrapping could be good:

```py
#         DO WHAT THE FUCK YOU WANT TO PUBLIC LICENSE 
#                     Version 2, December 2004 
# 
#  Copyright (C) 2020 Xu Siyuan <inqb@protonmail.com> 
# 
#  Everyone is permitted to copy and distribute verbatim or modified 
#  copies of this license document, and changing it is allowed as long 
#  as the name is changed. 
# 
#             DO WHAT THE FUCK YOU WANT TO PUBLIC LICENSE 
#    TERMS AND CONDITIONS FOR COPYING, DISTRIBUTION AND MODIFICATION 
# 
#   0. You just DO WHAT THE FUCK YOU WANT TO.

from dataclasses import dataclass, field

MISSING = object()
__all__ = ['property_field', 'property_dataclass']


class property_field:
    def __init__(self, fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None, **kwargs):
        self.field = field(**kwargs)
        self.property = property(fget, fset, fdel, doc)

    def getter(self, fget):
        self.property = self.property.getter(fget)
        return self

    def setter(self, fset):
        self.property = self.property.setter(fset)
        return self

    def deleter(self, fdel):
        self.property = self.property.deleter(fdel)
        return self


def property_dataclass(cls=MISSING, / , **kwargs):
    if cls is MISSING:
        return lambda cls: property_dataclass(cls, **kwargs)
    remembers = {}
    for k in dir(cls):
        if isinstance(getattr(cls, k), property_field):
            remembers[k] = getattr(cls, k).property
            setattr(cls, k, getattr(cls, k).field)
    result = dataclass(**kwargs)(cls)
    for k, p in remembers.items():
        setattr(result, k, p)
    return result
```

You can use it like this:

```py
@property_dataclass
class B:
    x: int = property_field(default_factory=int)

    @x.getter
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value
```

Comment: Aesthetically pleasing, but **computationally intense.** `property_dataclass()` is `O(n)` time complexity (where `n` is the number of attributes of the decorated class) with large non-negligible constants. That's possibly fine for trivial dataclasses but rapidly devolves into a stew of CPU churn for non-trivial dataclasses – especially where inheritance is involved. The computational intensity of the core `@dataclass` decorator itself only compounds this concern.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I did to define the field as a property in `__post_init__`. This is a total hack, but it works with `dataclasses` dict-based initialization and even with [marshmallow_dataclasses](https://github.com/lovasoa/marshmallow_dataclass).

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, asdict


@dataclass
class Test:
    name: str = "schbell"
    _name: str = field(init=False, repr=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        # Just so that we don't create the property a second time.
        if not isinstance(getattr(Test, "name", False), property):
            self._name = self.name
            Test.name = property(Test._get_name, Test._set_name)

    def _get_name(self):
        return self._name

    def _set_name(self, val):
        self._name = val


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = Test()
    print(t1)
    print(t1.name)
    t1.name = "not-schbell"
    print(asdict(t1))

    t2 = Test("llebhcs")
    print(t2)
    print(t2.name)
    print(asdict(t2))
```

This would print:

```
Test(name='schbell')
schbell
{'name': 'not-schbell', '_name': 'not-schbell'}
Test(name='llebhcs')
llebhcs
{'name': 'llebhcs', '_name': 'llebhcs'}
```

I actually started off from this [blog post](https://florimond.dev/blog/articles/2018/10/reconciling-dataclasses-and-properties-in-python/) mentioned somewhere in this SO, but ran into the issue that the dataclass field was being set to type `property` because the decorator is applied to the class. That is,

```py
@dataclass
class Test:
    name: str = field(default='something')
    _name: str = field(init=False, repr=False)

    @property
    def name():
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, val):
        self._name = val
```

would make `name` to be of type `property` and not `str`. So, the setter will actually receive `property` object as the argument instead of the field default.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way which allows you to have fields without a leading underscore:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str = property

    @name
    def name(self) -> str:
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value) -> None:
        self._name = value

    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        if isinstance(self.name, property):
            self.name = 'Default'
```

The result is:

```
print(Person().name)  # Prints: 'Default'
print(Person('Joel').name)  # Prints: 'Joel'
print(repr(Person('Jane')))  # Prints: Person(name='Jane')
```

Comment: The only issue with this approach (at least that I'm aware of) is that PyCharm complains when accessing or reading the property. For example:
`print(p.name)`
`assert p.name == 'test'`.
I guess the workaround might be to assign it like `name: str = None` and decorate with `@property` itself; PyCharm still complains at the implementation level, but on the client side the warnings now seem to disappear.

Answer (score 2):

This method of using properties in dataclasses also works with `asdict` and is simpler too. Why? Fields that are typed with `ClassVar` are ignored by the dataclass, but we can still use them in our properties.

```
@dataclass
def SomeData:
    uid: str
    _uid: ClassVar[str]

    @property
    def uid(self) -> str:
        return self._uid

    @uid.setter
    def uid(self, uid: str) -> None:
        self._uid = uid
```

Comment: The IDE seems to complain if calling the constructor with no arguments, so I'd probably suggest defining it like `uid: str = None`. Of course the one other issue is that `uid` is set to a property object if no value is provided via the constructor, but that can easily be resolved with help of a decorator for example.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so this is my first attempt at having everything self-contained within the class.

I tried a couple different approaches, including having a class decorator right next to `@dataclass` above the class definition. The issue with the decorator version is that my IDE complains if I decide to use it, and then I lose most of the type hints that the `dataclass` decorator provides. For example, if I'm trying to pass a field name into the constructor method, it doesn't auto-complete anymore when I add a new class decorator. I suppose that makes sense since the IDE assumes a decorator overwrites the original definition in some important way, however that succeeded in convincing me not to try with the decorator approach.

I ended up adding a metaclass to update the properties associated with dataclass fields to check if the value passed to the `setter` is a property object as mentioned by a few other solutions, and that seems to be working well enough now. Either of the two approaches below should work for testing (based on *@Martin CR*'s solution)

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class Test(metaclass=dataclass_property_support):
    name: str = property
    _name: str = field(default='baz', init=False, repr=False)

    @name
    def name(self) -> str:
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value: str) -> None:
        self._name = value

    # --- other properties like these should not be affected ---
    @property
    def other_prop(self) -> str:
        return self._other_prop

    @other_prop.setter
    def other_prop(self, value):
        self._other_prop = value
```

And here is an approach which (implicitly) maps the property `_name` that begins with an underscore to the dataclass field `name`:

```
@dataclass
class Test(metaclass=dataclass_property_support):
    name: str = 'baz'

    @property
    def _name(self) -> str:
        return self._name[::-1]

    @_name.setter
    def _name(self, value: str):
        self._name = value[::-1]
```

I personally prefer the latter approach, because it looks a little cleaner in my opinion and also the field `_name` doesn't show up when invoking the dataclass helper function `asdict` for example.

The below should work for testing purposes with either of the approaches above. The best part is my IDE doesn't complain about any of the code either.

```
def main():
    obj = Test(name='foo')
    print(obj)                  # displays: Test(name='foo')

    obj = Test()
    obj.name = 'bar'
    print(obj)                  # displays: Test(name='bar')

    obj = Test()
    print(obj)                  # displays: Test(name='baz')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Finally, here is the definition for the metaclass `dataclass_property_support` that now seems to be working:

```
from dataclasses import MISSING, Field
from functools import wraps
from typing import Dict, Any, get_type_hints


def dataclass_property_support(*args, **kwargs):
    """Adds support for using properties with default values in dataclasses."""
    cls = type(*args, **kwargs)

    # the args passed in to `type` will be a tuple of (name, bases, dict)
    cls_dict: Dict[str, Any] = args[2]

    # this accesses `__annotations__`, but should also work with sub-classes
    annotations = get_type_hints(cls)

    def get_default_from_annotation(field_: str):
        """Get the default value for the type annotated on a field"""
        default_type = annotations.get(field_)
        try:
            return default_type()
        except TypeError:
            return None

    for f, val in cls_dict.items():

        if isinstance(val, property):
            public_f = f.lstrip('_')

            if val.fset is None:
                # property is read-only, not settable
                continue

            if f not in annotations and public_f not in annotations:
                # adding this to check if it's a regular property (not
                # associated with a dataclass field)
                continue

            try:
                # Get the value of the field named without a leading underscore
                default = getattr(cls, public_f)
            except AttributeError:
                # The public field is probably type-annotated but not defined
                #   i.e. my_var: str
                default = get_default_from_annotation(public_f)
            else:
                if isinstance(default, property):
                    # The public field is a property
                    # Check if the value of underscored field is a dataclass
                    # Field. If so, we can use the `default` if one is set.
                    f_val = getattr(cls, '_' + f, None)
                    if isinstance(f_val, Field) \
                            and f_val.default is not MISSING:
                        default = f_val.default
                    else:
                        default = get_default_from_annotation(public_f)

            def wrapper(fset, initial_val):
                """
                Wraps the property `setter` method to check if we are passed
                in a property object itself, which will be true when no
                initial value is specified (thanks to @Martin CR).

                """
                @wraps(fset)
                def new_fset(self, value):
                    if isinstance(value, property):
                        value = initial_val
                    fset(self, value)
                return new_fset

            # Wraps the `setter` for the property
            val = val.setter(wrapper(val.fset, default))

            # Replace the value of the field without a leading underscore
            setattr(cls, public_f, val)

            # Delete the property if the field name starts with an underscore
            # This is technically not needed, but it supports cases where we
            # define an attribute with the same name as the property, i.e.
            #    @property
            #    def _wheels(self)
            #        return self._wheels
            if f.startswith('_'):
                delattr(cls, f)

    return cls
```

---

**Update (10/2021):**

I've managed to encapsulate the above logic - including support for additional edge cases - into the helper library [`dataclass-wizard`](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), in case this is of interest to anyone. You can find out more about [using field properties](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using_field_properties.html) in the linked documentation as well. Happy coding!

**Update (11/2021):**

A more performant approach is to use a metaclass to generate a `__post_init__()` on the class that only runs once to fix field properties so it works with dataclasses. You can check out [the gist](https://gist.github.com/rnag/d14b05680094b871935a9a30d43d5c0d) here which I added. I was able to test it out and when creating multiple class instances, this approach is optimized as it sets everything up properly the first time `__post_init__()` is run.

Answer (score 1):

Following a very thorough post about data classes and properties that can be found [here](https://florimond.dev/blog/articles/2018/10/reconciling-dataclasses-and-properties-in-python/) the TL;DR version which solves some very ugly cases where you have to call `MyClass(_my_var=2)` and strange `__repr__` outputs:

```py
from dataclasses import field, dataclass

@dataclass
class Vehicle:

    wheels: int
    _wheels: int = field(init=False, repr=False)

    def __init__(self, wheels: int):
       self._wheels = wheels

    @property
    def wheels(self) -> int:
         return self._wheels

    @wheels.setter
    def wheels(self, wheels: int):
        self._wheels = wheels
```

Comment: You neither need nor want to create an instance attribute named `wheels`. If you want `__init__` to initialize `_wheels` via the setter, use `wheels  = InitVar[int]`, then use `__post_init__` to set `self.wheels = wheels`.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the field definition after the property:

```py
@dataclasses.dataclass
class Test:
    @property
    def driver(self):
        print("In driver getter")
        return self._driver

    @driver.setter
    def driver(self, value):
        print("In driver setter")
        self._driver = value

    _driver: typing.Optional[str] =\
        dataclasses.field(init=False, default=None, repr=False)
    driver: typing.Optional[str] =\
       dataclasses.field(init=False, default=driver)
```

```
>>> t = Test(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
>>> t = Test()
>>> t._driver is None
True
>>> t.driver is None
In driver getter
True
>>> t.driver = "asdf"
In driver setter
>>> t._driver == "asdf"
True
>>> t
In driver getter
Test(driver='asdf')
```

I'm surprised this isn't already an answer but I question its wisdom. The only reason for this answer is to include the property in the representation - because the property's backing store (`_driver`) is already included in comparison tests and equality tests and so on. For example, this is a common idiom:

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self._driver = "default"

    @property
    def driver(self):
        if self._driver == "default":
            self._driver = "new"
        return self._driver
```

```
>>> t = Test()
>>> t
<__main__.Test object at 0x6fffffec11f0>
>>> t._driver
'default'
>>> t.driver
'new'
```

Here is the dataclass equivalent - except that it adds the property to the representation. In the standard class, the result of `(t._driver,t.driver)` is `("default","new")`. Notice that the result from the dataclass is instead `("new","new")`. This is a very simple example but you must recognize that including properties with possible side effects in special methods may not be the best idea.

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class Test:
    @property
    def driver(self):
        print("In driver getter")
        if self._driver == "default":
            self._driver = "new"
        return self._driver

    _driver: typing.Optional[str] =\
        dataclasses.field(init=False, default="default", repr=False)

    driver: typing.Optional[str] =\
       dataclasses.field(init=False, default=driver)
```

```
>>> t = Test()
>>> t
In driver getter
Test(driver='new')
>>> t._driver
'new'
>>> t.driver
In driver getter
'new'
```

So I would recommend just using:

```py
@dataclasses.dataclass
class Test:
    _driver: typing.Optional[str] =\
        dataclasses.field(init=False, default="default", repr=False)

    @property
    def driver(self):
        print("In driver getter")
        if self._driver == "default":
            self._driver = "new"
        return self._driver
```

```
>>> t
Test()
>>> t._driver
'default'
>>> t.driver
In driver getter
'new'
```

And you can sidestep the entire issue, avoiding `dataclasses` for initialization, by simply using `hasattr` in the property getter.

```py
@dataclasses.dataclass
class Test:
    @property
    def driver(self):
        print("In driver getter")
        if not hasattr(self, "_driver"):
            self._driver = "new"
        return self._driver
```

Or by using `__post_init__`:

```py
@dataclasses.dataclass
class Test:
    def __post_init__(self):
        self._driver = None

    @property
    def driver(self):
        print("In driver getter")
        if self._driver is None:
            self._driver = "new"
        return self._driver
```

Why do this? Because `init=False` dataclass defaults are stored only on the class and not the instance.

Answer (score 1):

The cleaner syntax I found ... is by re-implementing `property` and which forfeits the need to define the underlying `_name` attribute, as in:
(See full code below)

```
@dataclass
class myclass:
    name: MyProperty[in] = MyProperty[int](5)

    @name.getter
    def name_get(self) -> int:
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name_set(self, val: int) -> None
        self._name = val
```

One can obviously do this too:

```
@dataclass
class myclass:
    def name_get(self) -> int:
        return self._name

    name: MyProperty[in] = MyProperty[int](5, fget=name_get)
```

But it doesn't feel so clean.

To double down ... the new `property` decorator is also a `dataclass` itself

The deletion of the attribute can be controlled as in

- After deletion, if a default value was set for the class, it will be returned
- After deletion, if no default value was set, `AttributeError` will be raised
- If `fulldel` is `True` (default in the sample code) when instantiating the descriptor, after deletion `AttributeError` will be raised

Both `mypy` and `pyright` are happy with the `typing`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8; py-indent-offset:4 -*-
###############################################################################
from __future__ import annotations
from collections.abc import Callable
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Any, ClassVar, Generic, Optional, overload, TypeVar, Union
from typing_extensions import TypeAlias  # python 3.10
from typing_extensions import Self  # python 3.11

# Type to be wrapped by the descriptor
T = TypeVar('T')

GETTER: TypeAlias = Callable[[Any], T]
SETTER: TypeAlias = Callable[[Any, T], None]
DELETER: TypeAlias = Callable[[Any], None]


@dataclass
class MyProperty(Generic[T]):
    MISSING: ClassVar[object] = object()

    val: Union[T, object] = MISSING

    fget: Optional[GETTER] = None
    fset: Optional[SETTER] = None
    fdel: Optional[DELETER] = None

    p_prefix: str = field(default='_', kw_only=True)
    p_suffix: str = field(default='', kw_only=True)
    fulldel: bool = field(default=True, kw_only=True)

    name: str = field(default='', init=False)  # property name
    pname: str = field(init=False)  # property underlying name

    def __set_name__(self, owner: type[Any], name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.pname = pname = f'{self.p_prefix}{name}{self.p_suffix}'
        setattr(owner, pname, self.val)

    def __set__(self, instance: Any, val: T) -> None:
        if self.fset is None:
            raise AttributeError(f'{self.name} cannot be set (no setter)')

        if val is self:  # dataclass setting descriptor as default value
            return

        self.fset(instance, val)

    # overloads allow typecheckers to discriminate actual return type
    @overload
    def __get__(self, instance: None, owner: type[Any]) -> Self:
        ...

    @overload
    def __get__(self, instance: Any, owner: type[Any]) -> T:
        ...

    def __get__(self, instance: Optional[Any], owner: type[Any]) -> Union[Self, T]:
        if self.fget is None:
            raise AttributeError(f'{self.name} cannot be got (no getter)')

        if instance is None:  # class level access ... return descriptor
            return self

        if (val := self.fget(instance)) is self.MISSING:
            raise AttributeError(f'{self.name} not set or deleted')

        return val

    def __delete__(self, instance: Optional[Any]) -> None:
        if self.fdel is None:
            raise AttributeError(f'{self.name} cannot be deleted (no deleter)')

        if instance is None:  # class level access ... return descriptor
            return

        self.fdel(instance)
        if self.fulldel:
            setattr(instance, self.pname, self.MISSING)

    # descriptor attributes for method decoration
    def getter(self, f: GETTER) -> None:
        self.fget = f

    def setter(self, f: SETTER) -> None:
        self.fset = f

    def deleter(self, f: DELETER) -> None:
        self.fdel = f
```

Test Code

```
@dataclass
class test:
    a_value: MyProperty[int] = MyProperty[int](5, fulldel=False)
    b_value: MyProperty[int] = MyProperty[int](10, fulldel=True)
    c_value: MyProperty[int] = MyProperty[int]()

    @a_value.getter
    def a_value_get(self) -> int:
        return self._a_value

    @a_value.setter
    def a_value_set(self, val: int) -> None:
        self._a_value = val

    @a_value.deleter
    def a_value_del(self) -> None:
        delattr(self, '_a_value')

    @b_value.getter
    def b_value_get(self) -> int:
        return self._b_value

    @b_value.setter
    def b_value_set(self, val: int) -> None:
        self._b_value = val

    @b_value.deleter
    def b_value_del(self) -> None:
        delattr(self, '_b_value')

    @c_value.getter
    def c_value_get(self) -> int:
        return self._c_value

    @c_value.setter
    def c_value_set(self, val: int) -> None:
        self._c_value = val

    @c_value.deleter
    def c_value_del(self) -> None:
        delattr(self, '_c_value')


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
t = test()
print('-' * 10, 'a')
print(t.a_value)
t.a_value = 25
print(t.a_value)
delattr(t, 'a_value')
print(t.a_value)  # default class value again
print('-' * 10, 'b')
print(t.b_value)
t.b_value = 35
print(t.b_value)
delattr(t, 'b_value')
try:
    print(t.b_value)  # default class value again
except AttributeError:
    print('Got AttributeError after deletion')
print('-' * 10, 'c')
try:
    print(t.c_value)
except AttributeError:
    print('AttributeError ... because it has no default value')

t.c_value = 45
print(t.c_value)
delattr(t, 'c_value')
try:
    print(t.c_value)  # default class value again
except AttributeError:
    print('Got AttributeError after deletion')

print('-' * 10, 'repr')
t.b_value = 10
t.c_value = 20
print(f'{t!r}')
```

Output

```
---------- a
5
25
5
---------- b
10
35
Got AttributeError after deletion
---------- c
AttributeError ... because it has no default value
45
Got AttributeError after deletion
---------- repr
test(a_value=5, b_value=10, c_value=20)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the ideas from above, I created a class decorator function `resolve_abc_prop` that creates a new class containing the getter and setter functions as suggested
by @shmee.

```py
def resolve_abc_prop(cls):
    def gen_abstract_properties():
        """ search for abstract properties in super classes """

        for class_obj in cls.__mro__:
            for key, value in class_obj.__dict__.items():
                if isinstance(value, property) and value.__isabstractmethod__:
                    yield key, value

    abstract_prop = dict(gen_abstract_properties())

    def gen_get_set_properties():
        """ for each matching data and abstract property pair, 
            create a getter and setter method """

        for class_obj in cls.__mro__:
            if '__dataclass_fields__' in class_obj.__dict__:
                for key, value in class_obj.__dict__['__dataclass_fields__'].items():
                    if key in abstract_prop:
                        def get_func(self, key=key):
                            return getattr(self, f'__{key}')

                        def set_func(self, val, key=key):
                            return setattr(self, f'__{key}', val)

                        yield key, property(get_func, set_func)

    get_set_properties = dict(gen_get_set_properties())

    new_cls = type(
        cls.__name__,
        cls.__mro__,
        {**cls.__dict__, **get_set_properties},
    )

    return new_cls
```

Here we define a data class `AData` and a *mixin* `AOpMixin` implementing operations
on the data.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, replace
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class AOpMixin(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def x(self) -> int:
        ...

    def __add__(self, val):
        return replace(self, x=self.x + val)
```

Finally, the decorator `resolve_abc_prop` is then used to create a new class
with the data from `AData` and the operations from `AOpMixin`.

```py
@resolve_abc_prop
@dataclass
class A(AOpMixin):
    x: int

A(x=4) + 2   # A(x=6)
```

EDIT #1: I created a python package that makes it possible to overwrite abstract properties with a dataclass: [dataclass-abc](https://github.com/MichaelSchneeberger/dataclass-abc)

Answer (score 0):

After trying different suggestions from this thread I've come with a little modified version of @Samsara Apathika answer. In short: I removed the "underscore" field variable from the `__init__` (so it is available for internal use, but not seen by `asdict()` or by `__dataclass_fields__`).

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, InitVar, field, asdict

@dataclass
class D:
    a: float = 10.                # Normal attribut with a default value
    b: InitVar[float] = 20.       # init-only attribute with a default value 
    c: float = field(init=False)  # an attribute that will be defined in __post_init__
    
    def __post_init__(self, b):
        if not isinstance(getattr(D, "a", False), property):
            print('setting `a` to property')
            self._a = self.a
            D.a = property(D._get_a, D._set_a)
        
        print('setting `c`')
        self.c = self.a + b
        self.d = 50.
    
    def _get_a(self):
        print('in the getter')
        return self._a
    
    def _set_a(self, val):
        print('in the setter')
        self._a = val


if __name__ == "__main__":
    d1 = D()
    print(asdict(d1))
    print('\n')
    d2 = D()
    print(asdict(d2))
```

Gives:

```
setting `a` to property
setting `c`
in the getter
in the getter
{'a': 10.0, 'c': 30.0}


in the setter
setting `c`
in the getter
in the getter
{'a': 10.0, 'c': 30.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this idiom to get around the default value during `__init__` problem. Returning `None` from `__set__` if a property object is passed in (as is the case during `__init__`) will keep the initial default value untouched. Defining the default value of the private attribute as that of the previously defined public attribute, ensures the private attribute is available. Type hints are shown with the correct default value, and the comments silence the pylint and mypy warnings:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from pprint import pprint
from typing import Any

class dataclass_property(property): # pylint: disable=invalid-name

    def __set__(self, __obj: Any, __value: Any) -> None:
        if isinstance(__value, self.__class__):
            return None
        return super().__set__(__obj, __value)

@dataclass
class Vehicle:

    wheels: int = 1
    _wheels: int = field(default=wheels, init=False, repr=False)

    @dataclass_property # type: ignore
    def wheels(self) -> int:
        print("Get wheels")
        return self._wheels

    @wheels.setter # type: ignore
    def wheels(self, val: int):
        print("Set wheels to", val)
        self._wheels = val


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pprint(Vehicle())
    pprint('#####')
    pprint(Vehicle(wheels=4))
```

Output:

```bash
└─ $ python wheels.py 
Get wheels
Vehicle(wheels=1)
'#####'
Set wheels to 4
Get wheels
Vehicle(wheels=4)
```

Type hint:

[Type hint with correct default value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QswP.png)

Answer (score 0):

I went through the previous comments, and although most of them answer thet need to tweak the dataclass itself.
I came up with an approach using a decorator which I think is more concise:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import wrapt



def dataclass_properties(cls, property_starts='_'):
    
    @wrapt.decorator
    def wrapper(wrapped, instance, args, kwargs):
        properties = [prop for prop in dir(cls) if isinstance(getattr(cls, prop), property)]
        new_kwargs = {f"{property_starts}{k}" if k in properties else k: v for k, v in kwargs.items()}
        return wrapped(*args, **new_kwargs)
    return  wrapt.FunctionWrapper(cls, wrapper)()


@dataclass_properties
@dataclass
class State:
    _a: int
    b: int
    _c: int

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def time(self, value):
        self._a = value


if __name__=='__main__':
    s = State(b=1,a=2,_c=1)
    print(s)                 # returns: State(_a=2, b=1, _c=1)
    print(s.a)               # returns: 2
```

It can filter between properties and those variables that are not properties but start by "_".
It also supports the instantiation providing the property true name. In this case "_a".

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    s = State(b=1,_a=2,_c=1) 
    print(s)                 # returns: State(_a=2, b=1, _c=1)
```

I does not solve the problem of the representation though.

Answer (score -1):

For the use case that brought me to this page, namely to have a dataclass that is immutable, there is a simple option to use `@dataclass(frozen=True)`. This removes all the rather verbose explicit definition of getters and setters. The option `eq=True` is helpful too.

Credit: a reply from joshorr to [this post](https://florimond.dev/en/posts/2018/10/reconciling-dataclasses-and-properties-in-python/), linked in a comment to the accepted answer. Also a bit of a classical case of [RTFM](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#module-contents).