# How to make dataclass instance attribute non-public and an __init__ arg?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

If I want an instance attribute to be:

- Non-public (aka have a single leading underscore)
- Be a parameter in the `__init__` signature

Normally, I would do this:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar: str):
        self._bar = bar

foo = Foo(bar="bar")  # foo.bar would raise an AttributeError
```

However, in `dataclasses`, I'm unsure how to do this.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Foo:
    bar: str  # This leaves bar as a public instance attribute
```

What is the correct way to do this in `dataclasses.dataclass`?

Comment: If you've got private attributes, you probably shouldn't be using `dataclasses`. A dataclass is intended to just be a simple data holder (hence the "data" name), not something with opaque private state.

Comment: Yeah, going to second that actually. I did find an explanation here of how to do it (see solution #5), but it doesn't seem like a good idea. https://florimond.dev/blog/articles/2018/10/reconciling-dataclasses-and-properties-in-python/

Comment: Yeah I just read that article.  Seems to be an answer, but I agree, it's unwieldy.  Guess I should stick to a regular class for my use case, thank you both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be an `__init__()` argument, just write your own which will prevent one from being automatically generated. Note that specifying `init=False` as shown below isn't really required since it wouldn't have happened anyway, but nevertheless seems like good way to draw attention to what's going on. For the same reason, specifying `field(init=False)` for the private `_bar` field is superfluous.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass(init=False)
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar: str):
        self._bar = bar

    _bar: str = field(init=False)


foo = Foo(bar="xyz")
print(foo._bar)  # -> xyz
print(foo.bar)  # -> AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a relatively simple case for an `InitVar` and the `__post_init__` method. (Though the verbosity is probably not what you had in mind.)

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, InitVar


@dataclass
class Foo:
    bar: InitVar[str]

    def __post_init__(self, bar):
        self._bar = bar
```

This behaves as you described. `bar` (as written) is a required argument to `__init__`, but does not make an attribute named `bar`.

```
>>> f = Foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bar'
>>> f = Foo(9)
>>> f._bar
9
>>> f.bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

To be clear, this is something you would use in an *existing* dataclass; you wouldn't choose to create a dataclass just to do this.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51079503/dataclasses-and-property-decorator/64876093#64876093) you can find a big discussion on using `@property` in dataclasses which can resolve your problem (the `_bar` is safe under the setter/getter).

There could be some problems with unwanted attributes displayed as the output of `__repr__` or `asdict()`, which can be solved as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64876093/5805827)

---

PS I can't add a comment, so I've added a new answer.