# Required positional arguments with dataclass properties

Tags: python, properties, python-dataclasses

It seems there's been a fair bit of discussion about this already. I found [this post](https://florimond.dev/en/posts/2018/10/reconciling-dataclasses-and-properties-in-python/) particularly helpful, and it seems to provide one of the best solutions.

But there is a problem with the recommended solution.

Well, it seems to work great at first. Consider a simple test case without properties:

```py
@dataclass
class Foo:
    x: int
```

```py
>>> # Instantiate the class
>>> f = Foo(2)
>>> # Nice, it works!
>>> f.x
2
```

Now try to implement `x` as a property using the recommended solution:

```py
@dataclass
class Foo:
    x: int
    _x: int = field(init=False, repr=False)
    
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x
    
    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value
```

```py
>>> # Instantiate while explicitly passing `x`
>>> f = Foo(2)
>>> # Still appears to work
>>> f.x
2
```

But wait...

```py
>>> # Instantiate without any arguments
>>> f = Foo()
>>> # Oops...! Property `x` has never been initialized. Now we have a bug :(
>>> f.x
<property object at 0x10d2a8130>
```

Really the expected behavior here would be:

```py
>>> # Instantiate without any arguments
>>> f = Foo()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

It seems that the dataclass field has been overridden by the property... any thought on how to get around this?

**Related:**

- [Dataclasses and property decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51079503/dataclasses-and-property-decorator)

Answer (score 8):

Using a property in a dataclass that shares the name of an argument of the `__init__` method has an interesting side effect.  When the class is instantiated with no argument, the `property` object is passed as the default.

As a work-around, you can use check the type of `x` in `__post_init__`.

```
@dataclass
class Foo:
    x: int
    _x: int = field(init=False, repr=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        if isinstance(self.x, property):
            raise TypeError("__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'")

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value
```

Now when instantiating `Foo`, passing no argument raises the expected exception.

```
f = Foo()
# raises TypeError

f = Foo(1)
f
# returns
Foo(x=1)
```

---

Here is a more generalized solution for when multiple properties are being used.  This uses `InitVar` to pass parameters to the `__post_init__` method.  It DOES require that the the properties are listed first, and that their respective storage attributes be a the same name with a leading underscore.

This is pretty hacky, and the properties no longer show up in the `repr`.

```
@dataclass
class Foo:
    x: InitVar[int]
    y: InitVar[int]
    _x: int = field(init=False, repr=False, default=None)
    _y: int = field(init=False, repr=False, default=None)

    def __post_init__(self, *args):
        if m := sum(isinstance(arg, property) for arg in args):
            s = 's' if m>1 else ''
            raise TypeError(f'__init__() missing {m} required positional argument{s}.')

        arg_names = inspect.getfullargspec(self.__class__).args[1:]
        for arg_name, val in zip(arg_names, args):
            self.__setattr__('_' + arg_name, val)

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        self._y = value
```

Comment: I like that it is simple, but it feels quite hacky. Can you show a more general solution in case there are multiple property-fields without default values? Do we need to hardcode them into the post-init check?

Comment: @James the latter approach is a good idea, but it has a few flaws, at least from testing. For example if you define a dataclass field at the top like `a: str` not associated with a property, the `inspect.getfullargspec` call returns a 3-element tuple of [a, x, y] rather than the expected [x, y].

Comment: One other important thing I noted, is that the `__post_init__` sets the internal attributes and doesn't go through the property setter. At least, i feel it's a good idea to go through the property here, as it generally might have some validation logic in the setter method.

Answer (score 3):

Using properties in `dataclasses` actually has a curious effect, as [@James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5003756/james) also pointed out. In actuality, this issue isn't constrained to dataclasses alone; it rather happens due to the order in which you declare (or re-declare) a variable.

To elaborate, consider what happens when you do something like this, using just a simple class:

```py
class Foo:
    x: int = 2

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x
```

But watch what  happens when you now do:

```
>>> Foo.x
<property object at 0x00000263C50ECC78>
```

So what happened? Clearly, the `property` method declaration overwrote the attribute that we declared as `x: int = 2`.

In fact, at the time that the `@dataclass` decorator runs (which is once the class definition of `Foo` is complete), this is actually what it sees as the definition of `x`:

```
x: int = <property object at 0x00000263C50ECC78>
```

Confusing, right? It still sees the class annotations that are present in `Foo.__annotations__`, but it also sees the `property` object with a getter that we declared after the dataclass field. It's important to note that this result is not a bug in any way; however, since `dataclasses` doesn't explicitly check for a `property` object, it treats the value after the assignment `=` operator as a default value, and thus we observe a `<property object at 0x00000263C50ECC78>` passed in as a default value to the constructor when we don't explicitly pass a value for the field property `x`.

This is actually quite an interesting consequence to keep in mind. In fact, I also came up with a section on [Using Field Properties](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using_field_properties.html) which actually goes over this same behavior and some unexpected consequences of it.

#### Properties with Required Values

Here's a generalized *metaclass* approach that might prove useful for automation purposes, assuming what you want to do is raise a `TypeError` when values for any field properties are not passed in the constructor. I also created an optimized, modified approach of it in a [public gist](https://gist.github.com/rnag/d14b05680094b871935a9a30d43d5c0d).

What this metaclass does is generate a `__post_init__()` for the class, and for each field property declared it checks if a `property` object has been set as a default in the `__init__()` method generated by the `@dataclass` decorator; this indicates no value was passed in to the constructor for the field property, so a properly formatted `TypeError` is then raised to the caller. I adapted this metaclass approach from [@James's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69846550/10237506) above.

> Note: The following example should work in Python 3.7+

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from collections import deque
# noinspection PyProtectedMember
from dataclasses import _create_fn
from logging import getLogger

log = getLogger(__name__)


def require_field_properties(name, bases=None, cls_dict=None) -> type:
    """
    A metaclass which ensures that values for field properties are passed in
    to the __init__() method.

    Accepts the same arguments as the builtin `type` function::

        type(name, bases, dict) -> a new type
    """

    # annotations can also be forward-declared, i.e. as a string
    cls_annotations: dict[str, type | str] = cls_dict['__annotations__']
    # we're going to be doing a lot of `append`s, so might be better to use a
    # deque here rather than a list.
    body_lines: deque[str] = deque()

    # Loop over and identify all dataclass fields with associated properties.
    # Note that dataclasses._create_fn() uses 2 spaces for the initial indent.
    for field, annotation in cls_annotations.items():
        if field in cls_dict and isinstance(cls_dict[field], property):
            body_lines.append(f'if isinstance(self.{field}, property):')
            body_lines.append(f"  missing_fields.append('{field}')")

    # only add a __post_init__() if there are field properties in the class
    if not body_lines:
        cls = type(name, bases, cls_dict)
        return cls

    body_lines.appendleft('missing_fields = []')
    # to check if there are any missing arguments for field properties
    body_lines.append('if missing_fields:')
    body_lines.append("  s = 's' if len(missing_fields) > 1 else ''")
    body_lines.append("  args = (', and' if len(missing_fields) > 2 else ' and')"
                      ".join(', '.join(map(repr, missing_fields)).rsplit(',', 1))")
    body_lines.append('  raise TypeError('
                      "f'__init__() missing {len(missing_fields)} required "
                      "positional argument{s}: {args}')")

    # does the class define a __post_init__() ?
    if '__post_init__' in cls_dict:
        fn_locals = {'_orig_post_init': cls_dict['__post_init__']}
        body_lines.append('_orig_post_init(self, *args)')
    else:
        fn_locals = None

    # generate a new __post_init__ method
    _post_init_fn = _create_fn('__post_init__',
                               ('self', '*args'),
                               body_lines,
                               globals=cls_dict,
                               locals=fn_locals,
                               return_type=None)

    # Set the __post_init__() attribute on the class
    cls_dict['__post_init__'] = _post_init_fn

    # (Optional) Print the body of the generated method definition
    log.debug('Generated a body definition for %s.__post_init__():',
              name)
    log.debug('%s\n  %s', '-------', '\n  '.join(body_lines))
    log.debug('-------')

    cls = type(name, bases, cls_dict)
    return cls
```

And a sample usage of the metaclass:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from logging import basicConfig

from metaclasses import require_field_properties

basicConfig(level='DEBUG')


@dataclass
class Foo(metaclass=require_field_properties):
    a: str
    x: int
    y: bool
    z: float
    # the following definitions are not needed
    _x: int = field(init=False, repr=False)
    _y: bool = field(init=False, repr=False)
    _z: float = field(init=False, repr=False)

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        print(f'Setting x: {value!r}')
        self._x = value

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        print(f'Setting y: {value!r}')
        self._y = value

    @property
    def z(self):
        return self._z

    @z.setter
    def z(self, value):
        print(f'Setting z: {value!r}')
        self._z = value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo1 = Foo(a='a value', x=1, y=True, z=2.3)
    print('Foo1:', foo1)
    print()
    foo2 = Foo('hello', 123)
    print('Foo2:', foo2)
```

Output now appears to be as desired:

```
DEBUG:metaclasses:Generated a body definition for Foo.__post_init__():
DEBUG:metaclasses:-------
  missing_fields = []
  if isinstance(self.x, property):
    missing_fields.append('x')
  if isinstance(self.y, property):
    missing_fields.append('y')
  if isinstance(self.z, property):
    missing_fields.append('z')
  if missing_fields:
    s = 's' if len(missing_fields) > 1 else ''
    args = (', and' if len(missing_fields) > 2 else ' and').join(', '.join(map(repr, missing_fields)).rsplit(',', 1))
    raise TypeError(f'__init__() missing {len(missing_fields)} required positional argument{s}: {args}')
DEBUG:metaclasses:-------

Setting x: 1
Setting y: True
Setting z: 2.3
Foo1: Foo(a='a value', x=1, y=True, z=2.3)

Setting x: 123
Setting y: <property object at 0x10c2c2350>
Setting z: <property object at 0x10c2c23b0>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
    foo2 = Foo('hello', 123)
  File "<string>", line 7, in __init__
  File "<string>", line 13, in __post_init__
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y' and 'z'
```

---

So the above solution *does* work as expected, however it's a lot of code and so it's worth asking: why not make it *less* code, and rather set the `__post_init__` in the class itself, rather than go through a metaclass? The core reason here is actually performance. You'd ideally want to minimize the overhead of creating a new `Foo` object in the above case, for example.

So in order to explore that a bit further, I've put together a small test case to compare the performance of a metaclass approach against a `__post_init__` approach using the `inspect` module to retrieve the field properties of the class at runtime. Here is the example code below:

```py
import inspect
from dataclasses import dataclass, InitVar

from metaclasses import require_field_properties


@dataclass
class Foo1(metaclass=require_field_properties):
    a: str
    x: int
    y: bool
    z: float

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        self._y = value

    @property
    def z(self):
        return self._z

    @z.setter
    def z(self, value):
        self._z = value


@dataclass
class Foo2:
    a: str
    x: InitVar[int]
    y: InitVar[bool]
    z: InitVar[float]

    # noinspection PyDataclass
    def __post_init__(self, *args):
        if m := sum(isinstance(arg, property) for arg in args):
            s = 's' if m > 1 else ''
            raise TypeError(f'__init__() missing {m} required positional argument{s}.')

        arg_names = inspect.getfullargspec(self.__class__).args[2:]
        for arg_name, val in zip(arg_names, args):
            # setattr calls the property defined for each field
            self.__setattr__(arg_name, val)

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        self._y = value

    @property
    def z(self):
        return self._z

    @z.setter
    def z(self, value):
        self._z = value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from timeit import timeit

    n = 1
    iterations = 1000

    print('Metaclass:  ', timeit(f"""
for i in range({iterations}):
    _ = Foo1(a='a value' * i, x=i, y=i % 2 == 0, z=i * 1.5)
""", globals=globals(), number=n))

    print('InitVar:    ', timeit(f"""
for i in range({iterations}):
    _ = Foo2(a='a value' * i, x=i, y=i % 2 == 0, z=i * 1.5)
""", globals=globals(), number=n))
```

And here are the results, when I test in a Python 3.9 environment with `N=1000` iterations, with Mac OS X (Big Sur):

```
Metaclass:   0.0024892739999999997
InitVar:     0.034604513
```

Not surprisingly, the metaclass approach is overall more efficient when creating multiple `Foo` objects - on average about **10x** faster. The reason for this is it only has to go through and determine the field properties defined in a class once, and then it actually generates a `__post_init__` specifically for those fields. Overall the result is that it performs better, even though it technically requires more code and setup in order to get there.

#### Properties with Default Values

Suppose that you instead don't want to raise an error when `x` is not explicitly passed in to the constructor; maybe you just want to set a default value, like `None` or an `int` value like 3 for example.

I've created a metaclass approach specifically designed to handle this scenario. There's also the original [gist](https://gist.github.com/rnag/e8c641d7fed3e2967dd138d1ae249915) you can check out if you want an idea of how it was implemented (or you can also check out the [source code](https://github.com/rnag/dataclass-wizard/blob/main/dataclass_wizard/property_wizard.py#L15) directly if you're curious as well). In any case, here's the solution that I've come up with below; note that it involves a third-party library, as unfortunately this behavior is not baked into the `dataclasses` module at present.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass, field

from dataclass_wizard import property_wizard


@dataclass
class Foo(metaclass=property_wizard):
    x: int | None
    _x: int = field(init=False, repr=False)  # technically, not needed

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        print(f'Setting x to: {value!r}')
        self._x = value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = Foo(2)
    assert f.x == 2

    f = Foo()
    assert f.x is None
```

This is the output with the metaclass approach:

```
Setting x to: 2
Setting x to: None
```

And the output with the `@dataclass` decorator alone - *also as observed in the question above*:

```
Setting x to: 2
Setting x to: <property object at 0x000002D65A9950E8>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
    assert f.x is None
AssertionError
```

##### Specifying a Default Value

Lastly, here's an example of setting an explicit default value for the property, using a property defined with a leading underscore `_` to distinguish it from the dataclass field which has a public name.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

from dataclass_wizard import property_wizard


@dataclass
class Foo(metaclass=property_wizard):
    x: int = 1

    @property
    def _x(self):
        return self._x

    @_x.setter
    def _x(self, value):
        print(f'Setting x to: {value!r}')
        self._x = value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = Foo(2)
    assert f.x == 2

    f = Foo()
    assert f.x == 1
```

Output:

```
Setting x to: 2
Setting x to: 1
```

Comment: +1 for clarifying that the variable name is simply being overwritten by the property definition. I understood this, but of course it seems quite obvious when you consider that the same name is being assigned to twice in the same scope. I guess the only way is to move the property creation to a different scope, e.g. outside the class (as suggested by morlind in the comments to the linked article), or else into `__post_init__`. I actually wonder if this last option may not make the most sense.

Comment: @corvus I actually don't prefer moving the property creation outside the class, for the 
 same reasons I outlined in the linked article. For me the main issue is that it's easy to forget to add it if you're adding another field property to a class for example. I much rather prefer the `__post_init__` as mentioned (also the approach suggested by @James here) because it's contained within the class, and since it's near the top of the class definition it's easy to change or modify it as needed. The downside is I guess you'd need to do this manually for each new property you plan to add.

Comment: @corvus I've added a more general metaclass approach that can be used to automate the checking if a value is passed for field properties. It looks to be working so far, but probably worth making some improvements. I'll  leave it as it is for now.