# mypy doesn't recognize SQLAlchemy columns with hybrid_property

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mypy

I'm trying to use mypy with SQLAlchemy.
In order to validate/modify specific column value (`email` in this case), [SQLAlchemy official document](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapped_attributes.html#using-descriptors-and-hybrids) provides `hybrid_property` decorator.

The problem is, `mypy` doesn't recognize `EmailAddress` class constructor properly, it gives:

```
email_address.py:31: error: Unexpected keyword argument "email" for "EmailAddress"; did you mean "_email"?
```

How can I tell mypy to recognize these columns?

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

# I don't even like the following statements just for setter
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    hybrid_property = property
else:
    from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

Base = declarative_base()


class EmailAddress(Base):
    __tablename__ = "email_address"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    _email = Column("email", String)

    @hybrid_property
    def email(self):
        return self._email

    @email.setter
    def email(self, email):
        self._email = email


EmailAddress(email="foobar@example.com")
# email_address.py:31: error: Unexpected keyword argument "email" for "EmailAddress"; did you mean "_email"?
```

I'm using following packages:

```
SQLAlchemy==1.4.35
mypy==0.942
mypy-extensions==0.4.3
sqlalchemy2-stubs==0.0.2a22
```

Comment: Did you find a way to make it work so far?

Comment: @Welyweloo, Nah.  Assigning attributes after object initialization "technically" can avoid mypy errors, but it is far from what I want, like `email = EmailAddress()` then `email.email = "foobar@example.com"`

Comment: @Welyweloo, I've wrote my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems like I finally found a way to solve the problem.

This reminds me of uncooperative behaviors between dataclass/property decorators discussed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51079503/dataclasses-and-property-decorator).

I end up with splitting EmailAddress class into 2:

1. Use `@dataclass` decorator on base class in order to indicate constructor options.
2. Override `email` property so that mypy doesn't complain redef.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Optional

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import registry

mapper_registry: registry = registry()

# I don't even like the following statements just for setter
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    hybrid_property = property
else:
    from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property


@dataclass
@mapper_registry.mapped
class EmailAddressBase:
    __tablename__ = "email address"

    id: int = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email: Optional[str] = None


class EmailAddress(EmailAddressBase):
    _email = Column("email", String)

    @hybrid_property
    def email(self):
        return self._email

    @email.setter
    def email(self, email):
        self._email = email


email = EmailAddress(email="foobar@example.com")
print(email.email)
```